# Creating objects and linking them to a user in parse and JS

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have created the basic functionality of a system - I can currently register, log on, etc. I'm currently trying to implement a settings page where users would be able to add a list of classes to their account. I've looked around on the documentation but it's a bit unclear as to what I need to use. I think Collections seem the most appropriate, but again the documentation is a bit unclear. Could anybody clarify on the usage of this (and whether I should be using Collections for this), as well as possibly a link to a more in-depth documentation/tutorial?

Hope this made sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, you want to connect the user with the settings.

Therefore, maybe fiddle around with Current.User and it's functionalities [User Docs on Parse.com](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#users-props)

Also maybe a bit of a [starter tutorial](http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/playing-parsecom-api) which shows how to create favorites for a user, this requires Current.User and a Collection (the books), but you can also use settings as a collection (Collections are based on [Backbone Collections](http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-collection/)).

With settings it might be possible and better to create seperate columns in the User datatable and save the settings there. This way you don't have to make a seperate connection with the User and the collection.

Is this what you were looking for? It feels a bit vague..

Comment: This was very helpful, I appreciate the links. I know my question was very vague as I just started using Parse. I have since figured out a way to do what I am trying to achieve, but I'll have a look through the links you posted.

Comment: I also just started using Parse, I found out several things, but I am trying to learn more with it's user functionalities. I am therefore also quite curious how you solved your problem. Maybe can you give a small snippet or something of your code?

Comment: Hi Hendrik,
Once I had users created, I used to following code to create and link classes to users. Not sure if this is the most effective way but seems to be working fine for me. Hope this helps

`    var Class = Parse.Object.extend("Classes");
    var class = new Class();

    module.set("classname", document.getElementById("classname").value);
    module.set("user", Parse.User.current());

    module.save(null, {       
    success: function(item) {
      alert('saved');
    },`

What this does is add a property to the newly created module called User, and sets it to the current user.

Comment: Thanks for the code and your response! I don't mind not having the most effective way, now I at least have something to continue with!

Comment: I'm not sure how this website works as I just signed up, but if there's a way to send messages: if you have any more questions, I'd be happy to help as I only just started with Parse as well and may be able to help you out.
Regards

Comment: Thanks! I surely will get some more answers, and I am also happy to help you. You can for example sometimes look at the tag: parse.com, as this is usually used for answering questions. I look once a day if there are new questions. Otherwise, you can give me your email (mine is h.k.vlaanderen[at]gmail.com)